# Удаление дублирующихся строк в файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, строки, обработка

Есть текстовой файл, в нём 1000 Email-ов, каждый Email с новой строки. Часть из них повторяются. Необходимо, чтобы на выходе после обработки был файл только с уникальными Email-ами. Как это реализовать с помощью *Python 3*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый быстрый и простой способ убрать дубликаты из списка - преобразовать его к множеству. Конструктор множества [set()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?#set) принимает любой итерируемый объект, в том числе дескриптор файла. После чего остаётся только преобразовать множество обратно в строку и записать в другой файл:

```
with open('emails.txt') as in_fh, open('deduplicated.txt', 'w') as out_fh:
    out_fh.write(''.join(set(in_fh)))
```

Comment: @Ivan Ivshykov надо учитывать, что Email из set будут записаны в случайном порядке

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что код в ответе может сломаться, если последняя строчка не содержит перевод строки (или вообще для строк, которые  только пробелом отличаются).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы напечатать уникальные e-mail, заданные в файлах, указанных в командной строке, или из стандартного ввода:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

print("\n".join(set(map(str.strip, fileinput.input()))))
```

Пример:

```
$ dedup emails.txt >uniq-emails.txt
```

или:

```
$ dedup < emails.txt >uniq-emails.txt
```

Код работает даже, если невидимый пробел присутствует/отсутствует в строках. К примеру, последняя строчка в файле может иметь/не иметь новой строки—результат всё равно будет правильным.

---

Наличие `set()` ведёт к тому, что результат печатается в произвольном порядке, который может меняться от запуска к запуску. Чтобы эмулировать `sort -u emails.txt`, можно использовать [`groupby(sorted())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
from itertools import groupby

for line, _ in groupby(sorted(map(str.strip, fileinput.input()))):
    print(line)
```

Использование такое же: ввод читается из файлов или stdin, вывод печатается в stdout.

---

Для случая с e-mail это не нужно, но в общем случае, чтобы напечатать только уникальные строки из больших файлов, которые в памяти не умещаются—аналог`LC_ALL=C sort -u < input` в Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import contextlib
import heapq
import sys
from itertools import groupby
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from operator import itemgetter

def uniq(sorted_items):
    return map(itemgetter(0), groupby(sorted_items))

sorted_files = []
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    # sort lines in batches, write intermediate result to temporary files
    nbytes = 1 << 15 # read ~nbytes at a time
    for lines in iter(lambda f=sys.stdin.detach(): f.readlines(nbytes), []):
        lines.sort()
        file = stack.enter_context(TemporaryFile('w+b')) #NOTE: file is deleted on exit
        file.writelines(uniq(lines)) # write sorted unique lines
        file.seek(0) # rewind, to read later while merging partial results
        sorted_files.append(file) #NOTE: do not close the temporary file, yet

    # merge and write results
    sys.stdout = sys.stdout.detach() # suppress ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
    sys.stdout.writelines(uniq(heapq.merge(*sorted_files)))
```

Пример:

```
$ sort-u < emails.txt >uniq-emails.txt
```

В этом случае ввод принимается только со стандартного ввода и строки сравниваются как последовательности байт (предполагается что все строки заканчиваются на символ новой строки).

Связанный вопрос: [Sorting text file by using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14465154/4279).