# Python // Удалить повторяющиеся значения // Оставить первое уникальное

Tags: html, python, jinja2

Всем привет! Мне необходимо в html-документе удалить все дубликаты строк с определенным значением, но так, чтобы первое значение в документе осталось, может кто-нибудь привести пример? В голову что-то ничего не приходит...

Comment: в чём конкретно у вас вопрос? Что значит "строка" в рамка html-документа? Являются html-таги частью "строк"? При чём здесь jinja2? (template engine) Приведите явный пример ввода/вывода. Связанный вопрос [Удаление дублирующихся строк в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612103/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм:

```
elems = set()

for elem in последовательность:
   if elem in elems:
       последовательность.delete(elem)
   else:
       elems.add(elem)
```

Comment: А просто `set(последовательность)`? А как потом `html` собрать из множества?

Comment: Посмотрите еще раз. Множество нужно только для того чтобы знать что данный елемент у нас уже был. А `html` остаеться тот же, из него просто удаляються старые елементы.

Comment: Дейсвительно, что то туплю. Извеняюсь.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не совсем понял, как данный алгоритм применить к html документу

Comment: Ну откуда он у вас?

Comment: Он лежит в директории с проектом

Comment: Ну так тогда сначала его надо спарсить. Либо спецлиба, либо просто как обычный текст(хотя не уверен насчет последнего)

Comment: я не вижу ничего ни о html ни о jinja2 в ответе.¶ Ответ как есть, не будет работать, так как обычно нельзя изменять последовательность, которую вы обходите. [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)

Comment: @jfs Ну начнем с вопроса. В вопросе идет речь про `jinja2`(шаблонизатор) и он не может иметь какое либо отношение к файлу на диске(то что файл на диске взято из комментариев), и нет самодостаточного и воспроизводимого примера, там вообще ничего нет. Я не квантовый компьютер, на некорректный вопрос не могу возвратить корректный ответ, так что как есть. "так как обычно нельзя изменять последовательность," это догма. На самом деле можно менять если соблюдать некоторые условия.

Comment: Конкретно здесь `последовательность` это может быть быть хитрый класс маппинга `html` значений который вполне может поддерживать возможность корректного удаления во время итерации.

Comment: Вон ответ  от "Денис" в принципе не может корректно  работать на `html` и ничего, всем норм

Comment: если вы считаете вопрос настолько "некорректным", что на него нельзя дать "корректный" ответ, то зачем отвечать? Мне вот вопрос не ясен и я вместо ответа комментарий под вопросом оставил и проголосовал за закрытие (нельзя ответить на него в текущей форме — здесь мы с вами согласны).¶ если забыть о вопросе, у вас всё равно ответ вредный (по ссылке пройдите, чтобы понять почему не нужно удалять элементы как вы это делаете. Хитрую последовательность, которая удаляет правильно налету и с html работает в студию!).

Answer (score 0):

Разбиваем ваш файл на строки:

```
lines = open("file.html").readlines()
```

Удаляем повторяющиеся, сохраняя порядок строк:

```
result = sorted(set(lines), key=lines.index)
```