# Вывести общие цифры один раз

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def gen_nums(user_num_1, user_num_2):
  user_num_1 = list(str(user_num_1))
  user_num_2 = list(str(user_num_2))
  gen_nums = []
  for num_1 in user_num_1:
    for num_2 in user_num_2:
      if num_1 == num_2:
        gen_nums.append(num_1)
      
  return gen_nums


user_num_1 = 666
user_num_2 = 666
print(gen_nums(user_num_1, user_num_2))

# Вывод: ['6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6']
```

> Как написать код, чтобы он выводил повторяющуюся цифру один раз?

Comment: используйте для этого `set()`

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос чётко, с понятными условиями и примерами. Вот в вашем примере что нужно выдать: `6` или `666`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удаление дублирующихся строк в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612103/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ убрать из списка дубликаты - преобразовать его в множество и затем обратно в список:

Пример:

```
name_variable = ['2', '2', '2', 6, 6, 6]
print(list(set(name_variable)))

Вывод:
['2', 6]
```

Или:

```
name_variable = ['2', '2', '2', 6, 6, 6]
name_variable2 = list(set(name_variable))
print(name_variable2)

Вывод:
['2', 6]
```

Можно также пройтись циклом *for* и внутри задать условие не повторения, но это менее удобный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Формулировка вашего вопроса не совсем ясная, но как его понял я:

Сначала выберем **все** цифры из первого числа:

```
for num_1 in user_num_1:
  gen_nums.append(num_1)
```

и затем из другого числа **только те, которые не находятся в первом:**

```
for num_2 in user_num_2:
  if num_2 not in user_num_1:
    gen_nums.append(num_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBVsHMzIwrCUoXFGXmlWgo6Sgo6WXlZ@ZpFKeWaBSXFGkkamrqAWVSi4pTk0sy8xESSZog8P8/AA)

```
a = 666
b = 666
print(", ".join(set(str(a)).intersection(set(str(b)))))
```

```
6
```